# RxJava2 - how to observe an already initialised empty observable once it changes?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

so i have an Single that has already been initalized as a class member. it gets intialized like this:

var myObservable: Single = Observable.empty().toSingle()

this is defined as a class member.

Afterwards,later on after the class has already been initalized i finally get the actually response and i want this myObservable to now be the response :

```
  private fun callback(response:Response) {
                myObservable= Single.just(response)//now look, myObservable got changed, but im watching it in the zipWith call. how can i tell zip to watch this one now instead of the empty one i initialized ?


            }
```

but the problem with this is i am zipping two obervables at the very beginning  of the class call (and one of them is myObservable) and i am trying to listen for changes in both and take an action. here is the zipWith function:

```
  someApi.fetchOrders(orderNumber).zipWith<MyResponse,Pair<OrdersResponse,MyResponse>>(myObservable) { t1, t2 ->Pair(t1,t2)}
```

but i called this when myObservable was still initalized to empty. later when i got a response i changed it but really i assigned a new VALUE to the observable, i did not retain the same one i was watching in the zip. How can i UPDATE myObservable but keep the SAME reference that zipWith is watching ?

i tried changing myObservable into a subject and then when i zip it it looks like this instead:

someApi.fetchOrders(orderNumber).zipWith>(myObservable.toSingle()) { t1, t2 ->Pair(t1,t2)}

but it never executes the Function lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zipWith` emits when for both Observables emit, and pairs items with the same index. Your subject probably emitted when `fetchOrders` didn't, so zipWith didn't do anything. You can use subject and change `zipWith` to `subject.withLatestFrom(someApi.fetchOrders())`. Once you push something into the subject, `withLatestFrom` will emit with last value from `fetchOrders()`.

Comment: "zipWith waits for both Observables to complete until it emits." - are you sure, isn't it just the source `Observable` i.e `Observable.just(1).zipWith(Observable.interval(1L, SECOND))` when subscribed to would do `onNext(1)` then `onComplete`, as there are no more items to interleave, but interval could go on indefinitely? Documentation - "The operator subscribes to its sources in order they are specified and completes eagerly if one of the sources is shorter..."

Comment: You are right, I meant `zipWith` emits when both sources emit. But I have used it only with Singles so it was equivalent with completion. So zipWith emits Pairs with the same index, maybe your `fetchOrders` didn't emit enough times so your subject version didn't work as intended? https://rxmarbles.com/#zip

Comment: @Tuby do you know if withLatestForm emits if the observable is empty ?   so lets say i had apiCallSubject.withLatestFrom(someObservable).  will latestFrom emit if someObservable is empty or null ?

Comment: No, it will not emit. I see your problem now. But zipWith will not emit either

Comment: i didn't realize zipWith uses  same indexes.  so if observable1 is on index 2 and observable2 is on index 1 ,zipWith wont emit right ?

Comment: Yes, it will emit pairs of items with the same index